# What is the percentage increase in momentum if kinetic energy is increased by 4 percent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, momentum

What is the percentage increase in momentum if kinetic energy is increased by 4 percent? I have tried to solve it using trial and error method and have got 4 percent as my answer. Can you please give a better method?

Edit:I posted this Q when I was ney to SE, and this was closed for not following the rules...but now I know how to solve this and again want to open this. Can I do it?

Comment: There is no way to answer this question. You need to supply at least the mass of the object you are discussing.

Comment: The problem states that

$\frac{\left(.5v_2^2-.5v_1^2\right)}{.5v_1^2}=.04$

which simplifies to

$v_2=\sqrt{1.04}v_1$

so the percent increase in momentum is

$100\frac{\left(v_2-v_1\right)}{v_1}=100\frac{\left(\sqrt{1.04}v_1-v_1\right)}{v_1}$

which is 4%.

Comment: What was your method?

Comment: @SuchDoge You have found the error to be $1.98\;\%$ not $4\;\%$.

Comment: @Farcher you are correct, I made an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kinetic energy $E_{\rm K}= \dfrac 1 2 mv^2 \Rightarrow \dfrac{dE_{\rm K}}{dv} = mv$ and the momentum $p = mv \Rightarrow \dfrac{dp}{dv} = m$

For small changes $\dfrac{\Delta E_{\rm k}}{E_{\rm k}} \approx \dfrac {2\Delta v}{v}$ and $\dfrac{\Delta p}{p} \approx \dfrac{\Delta v}{v}$

If the percentage change in kinetic energy is $4\%$ then $\dfrac{2\Delta v}{v}$ equates approximately to $4\%$ and $\dfrac{\Delta v}{v}$ (the change in the momentum) equates to approximately $2\%$.

Working through the calculations exactly as was done by @SuchDoge gives $1.98\%$